# What is the difference between Php $this->$propery_name and $this->propery_name

Tags: php

```
    $protected_property_name = '_'.$name;
    if(property_exists($this, $protected_property_name)){
        return $this->$protected_property_name;
    }
```

I am following a tutorial on object-oriented programming, however, the instructor came up with a new code structure that I have not seen before without a clear explanation of why he did so. if you notice within the if(statement) the 
$this->$protected_property_name statement has two $ signs one for the $this and the other for the  $protected_property_name normally it should only be 
$this->protected_property_name without having a dollar sign on the protected_property_name variable. when I tried to remove the $ sign from the protected_property_name variable an error was triggered. the complete code looks like this

```
class Addrress{

  protected $_postal_code;

  function __get($name){
    if(!$this->_postal_code){
        $this->_postal_code = $this->_postal_code_guess();
    }

    //Attempt to return protected property by name  

    $protected_property_name = '_'.$name;
    if(property_exists($this, $protected_property_name)){
        return $this->$protected_property_name;
    }

    //Unable to access property; trigger error.
    trigger_error('Undefined property via __get:() '. $name);
    return NULL;        
}
}
```

Comment: `$this->property_name` simply points to a class property. `$this->$property_name` is "variable property". Here's the manual on the subject: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I am still confused can you please clarify. I read the manual but it still not making sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example class:

```
class Example {
    public $property_one = 1;
    public $property_two = 2;
}
```

You can see difference in following codes:

```
$example = new Example();
echo $example->property_one; //echo 1

$other_property = 'property_two';
echo $example->$other_property; // equal to $example->property_two and echo 2
```

Non-OOP example:

```
$variable_one = 100;
$variable_name = 'variable_one';
echo $$variable_name; // equal to echo $variable_one and echo 100
```

Comment: thanks, this was helpful. so basically the value of other_property var becomes a var itself??

Comment: In php you can define variable from string by double `$` sign. In above example `$$other_property` equal to `$property_two` variable. It's a special feature of php!

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume that we have a class

```
class Test {
   public $myAttr = 1;
}
var $x = new Test();
```

We can access the public attribute like $x->myAttr.

What if we have the name of the attribute in a variable, like

```
$var = 'myAttr';
```

We can access the value of the attribute with $x->$var